# Possible bug with pathlib.touch. Why does this raise FileNotFoundError?

Tags: python-3.x, pathlib

I have no way to explain the following exception in ipython. Why do the first two calls to `touch` succeed but the third fails?

```
from pathlib import Path
log_filename = Path('/mnt/c/Users/Michael/OneDrive/PycharmProjects/beta_numbers/logs/perron_numbers_log0.txt')
log_filename.touch() # success
log_filename = Path('/mnt/c/Users/Michael/OneDrive/PycharmProjects/beta_numbers/logs/perron_numbers_log_.txt')
log_filename.touch() # success
log_filename = Path('/mnt/c/Users/Michael/OneDrive/PycharmProjects/beta_numbers/logs/perron_numbers_log_0.txt')
log_filename.touch()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/pathlib.py", line 1166, in touch
    self._accessor.touch(self, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/pathlib.py", line 331, in touch
    fd = os.open(path, flags, mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/c/Users/Michael/OneDrive/PycharmProjects/beta_numbers/logs/perron_numbers_log_0.txt'
```

Contents of `/mnt/c/Users/Michael/OneDrive/PycharmProjects/beta_numbers/logs` prior to the first touch:

- -3_-1_-7.log
- -7_-29_-43.log
- -8_-3_-17.log
- -9_-35_-51.log
- analyze.log
- find_close_orbit.log
- test_log.txt
- testy.log
- update_legacy_data.log

Technical details: I am using the SageMath 9.5 virtual environment through WSL2 on a Windows 10 device. Python version: 3.10.4.

Comment: Can't reproduce or explain the issue you're seeing there but `pathlib` will raise a `FileNotFoundError` in certain other circumstances such as when you try to `touch` a file in a directory which doesn't exist which can be confusing. So just make sure you have run `mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True` on the path in which you are trying to `touch` a file first